# Directory iterator value as variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to transfer output of `std:filesystem` `directory_iterator` to vector or variable. Keep getting error: `no operator "=" matches these operands` -- operand types are: `std::string = const std::filesystem`

I am realively new to C++ and hit the wall at this point. Previously I have been using system commands but would like to avoid it in the future.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string objectInDirectory = "Jabberwocky";
    string dirlisted = "";
    for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(dirlisted)) {
        cout << "Next directory entry: " << entry.path() << endl;
        objectInDirectory = entry.path();
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`entry.path()` [returns a](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/path) `const std::filesystem::path&`. This is not implicitly convertible to `std::string`, so you need to call its string function:

```
 objectInDirectory = entry.path().string();
```

Conversion to `string` is not necessary; you could assign it to a `std::filesystem::path` instead without needing a conversion. This can be more ideal because there are better built-in path-manipulation tools for `std::filesystem::path` than `std::string`

Comment: Thank you for this one. Actually, conversion to string is a must as I need to use this later on as a string somewhere else.